# How do I know if a database trigger is DROP_TABLE or ALTER_TABLE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

If I create a database trigger in SQL Server 2008 which triggers on both DROP_TABLE and ALTER_TABLE, how do I determine whether this is a DROP or an ALTER?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the trigger you can test

```
SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]','sysname')
```

It will be `DROP_TABLE` or `ALTER_TABLE`

Documentation for [`EVENTDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173781%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)